# Provide schema while reading csv file as a dataframe in Scala Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql, spark-csv

I am trying to read a csv file into a dataframe. I know what the schema of my dataframe should be since I know my csv file. Also I am using spark csv package to read the file. I trying to specify the schema like below.

```
val pagecount = sqlContext.read.format("csv")
  .option("delimiter"," ").option("quote","")
  .option("schema","project: string ,article: string ,requests: integer ,bytes_served: long")
  .load("dbfs:/databricks-datasets/wikipedia-datasets/data-001/pagecounts/sample/pagecounts-20151124-170000")
```

But when I check the schema of the data frame I created, it seems to have taken its own schema. Am I doing anything wrong ? how to make spark to pick up the schema I mentioned ?

```
> pagecount.printSchema
root
|-- _c0: string (nullable = true)
|-- _c1: string (nullable = true)
|-- _c2: string (nullable = true)
|-- _c3: string (nullable = true)
```

Comment: which version of spark you are using ?

Answer (score 103):

Try the below code, you need not specify the schema. When you give inferSchema as true it should take it from your csv file.

```
val pagecount = sqlContext.read.format("csv")
  .option("delimiter"," ").option("quote","")
  .option("header", "true")
  .option("inferSchema", "true")
  .load("dbfs:/databricks-datasets/wikipedia-datasets/data-001/pagecounts/sample/pagecounts-20151124-170000")
```

If you want to manually specify the schema, you can do it as below:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

val customSchema = StructType(Array(
  StructField("project", StringType, true),
  StructField("article", StringType, true),
  StructField("requests", IntegerType, true),
  StructField("bytes_served", DoubleType, true))
)

val pagecount = sqlContext.read.format("csv")
  .option("delimiter"," ").option("quote","")
  .option("header", "true")
  .schema(customSchema)
  .load("dbfs:/databricks-datasets/wikipedia-datasets/data-001/pagecounts/sample/pagecounts-20151124-170000")
```

Comment: I tried executing the code but it gave me the below error.                                       val customSchema = StructType(Array(
    StructField("project", StringType, true),
    StructField("article", StringType, true),
    StructField("requests", IntegerType, true),
    StructField("bytes_served", DoubleType, true)))                                         <console>:30: error: not found: value StructType
       val customSchema = StructType(Array(

Comment: Theoretically I know we can mention the schema but I am lost on how to mention the schema in terms of syntax, is there any help that I can look up for ? I referred official documentation bit it do not mention this case and do not have much examples

Comment: This doesn't answer the question although it is helpful. How can he provide the schema?

Comment: When I tried the `option("inferSchema",  "true")`, I got `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Schema inference is not supported for format: csv. Please specify the schema.` This was for a readStream though, so maybe that's the difference.

Answer (score 24):

For those interested in doing this in Python here is a working version.

```
customSchema = StructType([
    StructField("IDGC", StringType(), True),        
    StructField("SEARCHNAME", StringType(), True),
    StructField("PRICE", DoubleType(), True)
])
productDF = spark.read.load('/home/ForTesting/testProduct.csv', format="csv", header="true", sep='|', schema=customSchema)

testProduct.csv
ID|SEARCHNAME|PRICE
6607|EFKTON75LIN|890.88
6612|EFKTON100HEN|55.66
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 18):

I'm using the solution provided by Arunakiran Nulu in my analysis (see the code). Despite it is able to assign the correct types to the columns, all the values returned are `null`. Previously, I've tried to the option `.option("inferSchema", "true")` and it returns the correct values in the dataframe (although different type).

```
val customSchema = StructType(Array(
    StructField("numicu", StringType, true),
    StructField("fecha_solicitud", TimestampType, true),
    StructField("codtecnica", StringType, true),
    StructField("tecnica", StringType, true),
    StructField("finexploracion", TimestampType, true),
    StructField("ultimavalidacioninforme", TimestampType, true),
    StructField("validador", StringType, true)))

val df_explo = spark.read
        .format("csv")
        .option("header", "true")
        .option("delimiter", "\t")
        .option("timestampFormat", "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss") 
        .schema(customSchema)
        .load(filename)
```

Result

```
root


|-- numicu: string (nullable = true)
 |-- fecha_solicitud: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- codtecnica: string (nullable = true)
 |-- tecnica: string (nullable = true)
 |-- finexploracion: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- ultimavalidacioninforme: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- validador: string (nullable = true)
```

and the table is:

```
|numicu|fecha_solicitud|codtecnica|tecnica|finexploracion|ultimavalidacioninforme|validador|
+------+---------------+----------+-------+--------------+-----------------------+---------+
|  null|           null|      null|   null|          null|                   null|     null|
|  null|           null|      null|   null|          null|                   null|     null|
|  null|           null|      null|   null|          null|                   null|     null|
|  null|           null|      null|   null|          null|                   null|     null|
```

Comment: It looks like `.option("timestampFormat", "yyyy/mm/dd HH:mm:ss")` should instead be `.option("timestampFormat", "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss")`.  [Notice the capital `MM` for month]  Otherwise it will be interpreting the month digits as the _minutes_ of the timestamp.

Comment: Yes! You are right! I didn't notice. I'll edit my answer. Thanks

Comment: If you have a DateType column which may contain 'null' values, set  `.option("nullValue", "null")` otherwise it considers entire row with null values.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem - did you ever get this working in scala?

Answer (score 16):

The previous solutions have used the custom StructType.

With spark-sql 2.4.5 (scala version 2.12.10) it is now possible to specify the schema as a string using the `schema` function

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession;
```

---

```
val sparkSession = SparkSession.builder()
            .appName("sample-app")
            .master("local[2]")
            .getOrCreate();

val pageCount = sparkSession.read
  .format("csv")
  .option("delimiter","|")
  .option("quote","")
  .schema("project string ,article string ,requests integer ,bytes_served long")
  .load("dbfs:/databricks-datasets/wikipedia-datasets/data-001/pagecounts/sample/pagecounts-20151124-170000")
```

Answer (score 13):

Thanks to the answer by @Nulu, it works for pyspark with minimal tweaking

```
from pyspark.sql.types import LongType, StringType, StructField, StructType, BooleanType, ArrayType, IntegerType

customSchema = StructType(Array(
    StructField("project", StringType, true),
    StructField("article", StringType, true),
    StructField("requests", IntegerType, true),
    StructField("bytes_served", DoubleType, true)))

pagecount = sc.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
         .option("delimiter"," ")
         .option("quote","")
         .option("header", "false")
         .schema(customSchema)
         .load("dbfs:/databricks-datasets/wikipedia-datasets/data-001/pagecounts/sample/pagecounts-20151124-170000")
```

Comment: Above code doesn't work In pyspark. What worked for me is:>>> customSchema = StructType().add("MovieID", IntegerType(), True).add("Title", StringType(), True).add("Genres", StringType(), True)
>>> df = sqlContext.read.format("csv").option("delimiter",",").option("header", "true").schema(customSchema).load("movies.csv")
>>> df
DataFrame[MovieID: int, Title: string, Genres: string]
>>>

Comment: The Array is not PySpark type. You should use the Python array [] instead of "Array". And use "True" instead of "true" in Python.

Answer (score 9):

> **schema definition as simple string**

Just in case if some one is interested in schema definition as simple string  with ***date*** and ***time stamp***

> **data file creation from Terminal or shell**

```
echo " 
2019-07-02 22:11:11.000999, 01/01/2019, Suresh, abc  
2019-01-02 22:11:11.000001, 01/01/2020, Aadi, xyz 
" > data.csv
```

> **Defining the schema as String**

```
    user_schema = 'timesta TIMESTAMP,date DATE,first_name STRING , last_name STRING'
```

> **reading the data**

```
    df = spark.read.csv(path='data.csv', schema = user_schema, sep=',', dateFormat='MM/dd/yyyy',timestampFormat='yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS')

    df.show(10, False)

    +-----------------------+----------+----------+---------+
    |timesta                |date      |first_name|last_name|
    +-----------------------+----------+----------+---------+
    |2019-07-02 22:11:11.999|2019-01-01| Suresh   | abc     |
    |2019-01-02 22:11:11.001|2020-01-01| Aadi     | xyz     |
    +-----------------------+----------+----------+---------+
```

> **Please note defining the schema explicitly instead of letting spark infer the schema also improves the spark read performance.**

Comment: val     user_schema = "timesta TIMESTAMP,date DATE,first_name STRING , last_name STRING"
    val mydf1 = spark.read.schema(user_schema).option("dateFormat","MM/dd/yyyy").option("timestampFormat","yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS").csv("data.csv")

Answer (score 4):

Here's how you can work with a custom schema, a complete demo:

$> shell code,

```
echo "
Slingo, iOS 
Slingo, Android
" > game.csv
```

Scala code:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

val customSchema = StructType(Array(
  StructField("game_id", StringType, true),
  StructField("os_id", StringType, true)
))

val csv_df = spark.read.format("csv").schema(customSchema).load("game.csv")
csv_df.show 

csv_df.orderBy(asc("game_id"), desc("os_id")).show
csv_df.createOrReplaceTempView("game_view")
val sort_df = sql("select * from game_view order by game_id, os_id desc")
sort_df.show
```

Comment: http://mujiang.blogspot.ca/2018/01/work-with-custom-schema-with-spark.html

Answer (score 0):

```
// import Library
import java.io.StringReader ;

import au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVReader

//filename

var train_csv = "/Path/train.csv";

//read as text file

val train_rdd = sc.textFile(train_csv)   

//use string reader to convert in proper format

var full_train_data  = train_rdd.map{line =>  var csvReader = new CSVReader(new StringReader(line)) ; csvReader.readNext();  }   

//declares  types

type s = String

// declare case class for schema

case class trainSchema (Loan_ID :s ,Gender :s, Married :s, Dependents :s,Education :s,Self_Employed :s,ApplicantIncome :s,CoapplicantIncome :s,
    LoanAmount :s,Loan_Amount_Term :s, Credit_History :s, Property_Area :s,Loan_Status :s)

//create DF RDD with custom schema 

var full_train_data_with_schema = full_train_data.mapPartitionsWithIndex{(idx,itr)=> if (idx==0) itr.drop(1); 
                     itr.toList.map(x=> trainSchema(x(0),x(1),x(2),x(3),x(4),x(5),x(6),x(7),x(8),x(9),x(10),x(11),x(12))).iterator }.toDF
```

Answer (score 0):

In pyspark 2.4 onwards, you can simply use `header` parameter to set the correct header:

```
data = spark.read.csv('data.csv', header=True)
```

Similarly, if using scala you can use `header` parameter as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do like this by using sparkSession and implicit

```
import sparkSession.implicits._
val pagecount:DataFrame = sparkSession.read
.option("delimiter"," ")
.option("quote","")
.option("inferSchema","true")
.csv("dbfs:/databricks-datasets/wikipedia-datasets/data-001/pagecounts/sample/pagecounts-20151124-170000")
.toDF("project","article","requests","bytes_served")
```

Answer (score 0):

if your spark version is 3.0.1, you can use following Scala scripts:

```
val df = spark.read.format("csv").option("delimiter",",").option("header",true).load("file:///LOCAL_CSV_FILE_PATH")
```

but in this way, all datatypes will be set as `String`.

Answer (score -1):

This is one of option where we can pass the column names to the dataframe while loading CSV.

```
import pandas
    names = ['sepal-length', 'sepal-width', 'petal-length', 'petal-width', 'class']
    dataset = pandas.read_csv("C:/Users/NS00606317/Downloads/Iris.csv", names=names, header=0)
print(dataset.head(10))
```

Output

```
    sepal-length  sepal-width  petal-length  petal-width        class
1            5.1          3.5           1.4          0.2  Iris-setosa
2            4.9          3.0           1.4          0.2  Iris-setosa
3            4.7          3.2           1.3          0.2  Iris-setosa
4            4.6          3.1           1.5          0.2  Iris-setosa
5            5.0          3.6           1.4          0.2  Iris-setosa
6            5.4          3.9           1.7          0.4  Iris-setosa
7            4.6          3.4           1.4          0.3  Iris-setosa
8            5.0          3.4           1.5          0.2  Iris-setosa
9            4.4          2.9           1.4          0.2  Iris-setosa
10           4.9          3.1           1.5          0.1  Iris-setosa
```

Comment: Good answer, but the question is referring to Spark DataFrame, not the one for Pandas

Answer (score -1):

here my solution is:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
  val spark = org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.builder.
  master("local[*]").
  appName("Spark CSV Reader").
  getOrCreate()

val movie_rating_schema = StructType(Array(
  StructField("UserID", IntegerType, true),
  StructField("MovieID", IntegerType, true),
  StructField("Rating", DoubleType, true),
  StructField("Timestamp", TimestampType, true)))

val df_ratings: DataFrame = spark.read.format("csv").
  option("header", "true").
  option("mode", "DROPMALFORMED").
  option("delimiter", ",").
  //option("inferSchema", "true").
  option("nullValue", "null").
  schema(movie_rating_schema).
  load(args(0)) //"file:///home/hadoop/spark-workspace/data/ml-20m/ratings.csv"

val movie_avg_scores = df_ratings.rdd.map(_.toString()).
  map(line => {
    // drop "[", "]" and then split the str 
    val fileds = line.substring(1, line.length() - 1).split(",")
    //extract (movie id, average rating)
    (fileds(1).toInt, fileds(2).toDouble)
  }).
  groupByKey().
  map(data => {
    val avg: Double = data._2.sum / data._2.size
    (data._1, avg)
  })
```