# Connecting is Slow with PySpark

Tags: python, hadoop, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am playing around with PySpark with the following code:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("Scoring System").getOrCreate()

df = spark.read.csv('output.csv')

df.show()
```

after I ran python trial.py on the command line it has been around 5 to 10 minutes, with no progression:

```
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
2019-05-05 22:58:31 WARN  Utils:66 - Service 'SparkUI' could not bind on port 4040. Attempting port 4041.
2019-05-05 22:58:32 WARN  Client:66 - Neither spark.yarn.jars nor spark.yarn.archive is set, falling back to uploading libraries under SPARK_HOME.
[Stage 0:>                                                          (0 + 0) / 1]2019-05-05 23:00:08 WARN  YarnScheduler:66 - Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources
2019-05-05 23:00:23 WARN  YarnScheduler:66 - Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources
2019-05-05 23:00:38 WARN  YarnScheduler:66 - Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources
2019-05-05 23:00:53 WARN  YarnScheduler:66 - Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources
[Stage 0:>                                                          (0 + 0) / 1]2019-05-05 23:01:08 WARN  YarnScheduler:66 - Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources
2019-05-05 23:01:23 WARN  YarnScheduler:66 - Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources
2019-05-05 23:01:38 WARN  YarnScheduler:66 - Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources
```

I am hunching that I am lacking resources in my worker node(?), or am I missing something?

Comment: What is the size of the file you are trying to read?

Comment: Hi @Vitaliy, Its around 21 GB.

Comment: My guess is that it is trying to infer the schema. Doing this requires loading a large portion of the file to understand the nature of the data. Try specifying the schema explicitly (this is a best practice in general). You can see an example of how to do this at https://stackoverflow.com/a/49281042/180650

Answer (score 0):

Try to increase the Number of Executors and memory 
**pyspark --num-executors 5 --executor-memory 1G**