# Spark Dataframe save as CSV

Tags: excel

```
ID,Score1,Score2,Total Score
user021,4/4,2/2,14.0/50.0
```

The above csv which generated using spark dataframe.

```
df.coalesce(1).write
      .mode("overwrite")
      .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
      .option("header", "true")
      .save(url)
```

When we open that CSV in the excel sheet for **Score1** and **Score2** columns are converted to **Date formate**.

Is there Any configurations to keep both column **Score1** and **Score2** as string formate instead of date formate?

Things which I tried but no luck!

```
 df.coalesce(1).write
      .mode("overwrite")
      .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
      .option("header", "true")
      .option("inferSchema", "false/true")
      .save(url)
```

I tried with `inferSchema` configuration but no luck in this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Provide schema while reading csv file as a dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39926411/provide-schema-while-reading-csv-file-as-a-dataframe)

Comment: All fields in the data frame are "string" data type only.

Comment: When the data type is string, How it got converted to date formate in the excel sheet? If I open CSV in the normal text editor I can see only `4/4`, not date formate.

Comment: Re:How it got converted to date formate in the excel sheet?. It is excel which is trying to interpret as it sees something like Date in that column. Once you open it in excel you can select that column and set the format as General or Text

Comment: This is an Excel question...

Comment: Is there any way to add double quotes to only numeric columns?