# Trying to Save Spark Dataframe to disk as CSV on DBFS

Tags: pyspark, databricks

I have found multiple results on how to save a Dataframe as CSV to disk on Databricks platforme.g.
[Spark Dataframe save as CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58131542/spark-dataframe-save-as-csv)
[How to save a spark DataFrame as csv on disk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33174443/how-to-save-a-spark-dataframe-as-csv-on-disk/38913345)

However, whenever I try to apply the answers to my situation it failed. Therefore, I am submitting my own question on the issue here.

I generate the following Dataframe with the following code:

```
df = spark.read.format(file_type) \
  .option("inferSchema", infer_schema) \
  .option("header", first_row_is_header) \
  .option("sep", delimiter) \
  .load(file_location)

display(df)
```

I would now like to save the above dataframe to disk.

I have tried the following:

```
filepath = "/FileStore/tables"
df.coalesce(1).write.option("header","true").option("sep",",").mode("overwrite").csv("filepath")
```

But I get the following error:
[image]

Can someone let me know where I'm going wrong?

Comment: I managed to figure out why I was getting the above error - its because I was trying to write to a Community Edition of Databricks. Everything worked fine when I applied to code to a paid for Databricks platform. However, the file is being saved as ```part-00000-tid-3693777652656899971-46f65adb-4641-446f-863f-eade3e2b3155-2-1-c000.csv``` . Can someone let me know how to rename the file to something more meaningful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sharing the answer as per the comment by the original poster:

"I managed to figure out why I was getting the above error - its because I was trying to write to a Community Edition of Databricks. Everything worked fine when I applied to code to a paid for Databricks platform".

**Answering question on comment:**

> Can someone let me know how to rename the file to something more
>   meaningful?

It's not possible to do it directly to change the file name in Spark's save.

Spark uses Hadoop File Format, which requires data to be partitioned - that's why you have part- files. You can easily change filename after processing just like in the [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40792434/spark-dataframe-save-in-single-file-on-hdfs-location?rq=1) thread.

You may refer similar [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41990086/specifying-the-filename-when-saving-a-dataframe-as-a-csv) thread, which addressed similar issue.

Hope this helps.