# Creating a dataframe and casting colums with inferSchema from a csv is way slower than creating one and casting with withColumn

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to create a dataframe in Spark by reading a csv, the problem is that if I don't do anything in particular the dataframe will have every column type as string:

```
root
 |-- ticker: string (nullable = true)
 |-- open: string (nullable = true)
 |-- close: string (nullable = true)
 |-- adj_close: string (nullable = true)
 |-- low: string (nullable = true)
 |-- high: string (nullable = true)
 |-- volume: string (nullable = true)
 |-- date: string (nullable = true)
```

In order to solve this I add the option "inferSchema" as true, like this:

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder
.appName("Job One")
.master("local")
.config("spark.eventLog.enabled", "true")
.config("spark.eventLog.dir", spark_events)
.getOrCreate()
import spark.implicits._

val df = spark.read
     .format("csv")
     .option("inferSchema", "true")
     .option("header", "true") 
     .option("mode", "DROPMALFORMED")
     .load(historicalStockPrices)

df.printSchema()
```

And this way I obtain this instead:

```
root
 |-- ticker: string (nullable = true)
 |-- open: double (nullable = true)
 |-- close: double (nullable = true)
 |-- adj_close: double (nullable = true)
 |-- low: double (nullable = true)
 |-- high: double (nullable = true)
 |-- volume: long (nullable = true)
 |-- date: string (nullable = true)
```

Which is what I want, but adding the option inferSchema makes so that the job takes 1.4 minutes instead of just 6 seconds when I don't add it.
Another method to obtain the columns with the types I want is by using withColumn, like this:

```
val df2 = df
.withColumn("open",df("open").cast("Float"))
.withColumn("close",df("close").cast("Float"))
.withColumn("adj_close",df("adj_close").cast("Float"))
.withColumn("low",df("low").cast("Float"))
.withColumn("high",df("high").cast("Float"))
.withColumn("volume",df("volume").cast("Long"))

df2.printSchema()
```

The result of the whole operation this time is just 6 seconds again.
What gives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your question: When you specify `.option("inferSchema", "true")` it needs to dynamically read the whole file as you do not specify a percentage. That takes a while. This is not done with big files often.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can help. Referring [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39927352/2451763), why don't you try creating your own schema of `StructType` and then right before `load`, you could use the `schema` method. So while reading the CSV, your code will look like:

```
//Assuming you've already created your schema

val df = spark.read
   .format("csv")
   .option("header", "true")
   .schema(customSchema) 
   .option("mode", "DROPMALFORMED")
   .load(historicalStockPrices)
```