# How do I Compare 2 Spark Dataframes in Databricks

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I have the following spark dataframes. One is derived from a text file while the other is derived from a Spark table in Databricks:

Despite the data being exactly the same, the following code reports differences. I expect df3 to be empty:

```
table_df = spark.sql("select * from db.table1")
file_df = spark.read.format("csv").load("my_file.txt", header = False, delimiter = '|')
file_df = file_df.toPandas()
table_df = table_df.toPandas()
df3=table_df.eq(file_df)
print(df3.shape[0])
```

- Do I need to order the data before comparison?  - If so how do I do that?
- I cant see where a join is done in the above. How will it match rows? [ID] and [Account] are primary keys?
- Is the above the best way to compare 2 dataframes?

Here is the data - where [ID] and [Account] are primary keys

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What I usually do to compare two dataframe is using doing an inner join and see if the count match, or use [`subtract`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.subtract) to see if there is any different between two of them

```py
df1 = create_df(
    data=[
        ('Avery Bradley', 25.0, 7730337.0),
        ('Jae Crowder', 25.0, 6796117.0),
    ],
    schema = ['name', 'age', 'salary']
)
+-------------+----+---------+
|         name| age|   salary|
+-------------+----+---------+
|Avery Bradley|25.0|7730337.0| <<< 25
|  Jae Crowder|25.0|6796117.0|
+-------------+----+---------+

df2 = create_df(
    data=[
        ('Avery Bradley', 24.0, 7730337.0),
        ('Jae Crowder', 25.0, 6796117.0),
    ],
    schema = ['name', 'age', 'salary']
)
+-------------+----+---------+
|         name| age|   salary|
+-------------+----+---------+
|Avery Bradley|24.0|7730337.0| <<< 24
|  Jae Crowder|25.0|6796117.0|
+-------------+----+---------+

# Solution #1
df1.subtract(df2).show()
+-------------+----+---------+
|         name| age|   salary|
+-------------+----+---------+
|Avery Bradley|25.0|7730337.0|
+-------------+----+---------+

# Solution #2
df1.join(df2, on=df1.columns).count()
# 1 <<< while df1.count() = 2
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response. Do you have sample code please?

Comment: I used solution #1. Now I see that the following line in my code converts the ID into decimal and that doesn't match with the whole number coming for the same column in the table: file_df = spark.read.format("csv").load("my_file.txt", header = False, delimiter = '|')

Comment: You always can force schema when reading from csv

Comment: You can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51762911/3441510) answer